# Converges uniformly on an arbitrary closed disc implies on every compact subsets

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, alternative-proof

Suppose that we have a given sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$. The goal is to show that it converges uniformly on every compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $R>0$ be arbitrary, and define, say, $C_R=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z-1|\leq R\}$. If one has shown that $(f_n)_{n\geq 0}$ converges uniformly on $C_R$, how do you conclude mathematically that it then converges uniformly on every compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$?

I can't find a correct way to conclude: obviously, I would just say that $R$ could be taken arbitrarily large, but in this case, what's been shown, is that it actually converges on every compact subsets containing $1$. See the definition of $C_R$, which is a closed disc around $1$ with centre $R$.

Comment: you can, for large enough $R$, to include into $C_R$, any compact set

Comment: Are you asking whether $(\exists R : U(C_R))\implies(\forall K: U(K))$ or whether $(\forall R :U(C_R))\implies(\forall K: U(K))$, where $U(S)$ means $f_n$ converges uniformly on $S$?

Comment: @kimchilover The last one

Comment: Do you know that $S\subseteq T$ implies $U(T)\implies U(S)$, where $U(A)$ means "converges uniformly on $A$"?  That's what's behind both posted answers .

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, I know this; how do I use this to conclude? That's the thing I don't know how to explain, if we had $T:=C_R$, how should I construct $S$ depending on $R$?

Answer (score 1):

Say that $K$ and $K'$ are two compact sets and $K \subset K'$. Then if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $K'$, it also converges uniformly on $K$.

Therefore to check that it converges uniformly on all compact subsets of the plane, you just need to give a family of compact subsets of the plane such that every compact subset of the plane is a subset of a member of the family. These disks are one such family.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not understand your second paragraph so well, which sets are which. Could you please reformulate it? I've managed to show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $C_R$. Since $R>0$ can be taken arbitrarily large, $(f_n)$ converges on every compact subsets of $C_R$ which are subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, or is $\bigcup_{R>0}C_R=\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: i believe she/he ment that the "family of compact sets" is $C_R$, for arbitrary $R$. Since you can choose $R$ as big as you like, then inside every compact lies into one $C_R$, for big enough $R$

Answer (score 0):

If $K$ is any compact set then $K \subseteq \{z: |z-1| \leq R\}$ for $R$ sufficiently large. Just take $R=1+\sup \{|z|:z \in K\}$.